# Json Value undefined when converting datatable into json format

Tags: asp.net, jquery, web-services

I want to retreive the data from database and assign it to dropdownlist. For that I'm using the following jquery in the onclick event

```
function getcountry() {
                try {

                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                        url: "/JsonWebServiceWithJQuery/jsonwebservice.asmx/getcountry",
                        data: "{}",
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        success: ajaxCallSucceed,
                        datatype: "json",
                        failure: ajaxCallFailed
                    });
                }
                catch (e) {
                    alert("Failed calling webservice" + e);
                }
            }
            function ajaxCallSucceed(response) {
                alert("Success");
                alert(response.d);
            }
            function ajaxCallFailed(error) {
                alert("I'm failed");
                alert('error: ' + error);
            }



    <input type="button" value="Get All Users" onclick="getcountry();" />
```

This is the webmethod I'm using for retreiving from database and also a conversion function to convert datatable into json format. It is retreiving correctly. But, the output is coming as undefined. I can't fix the bug.. Any help?

```
 public static string CreateJsonParameters(DataTable dt)
        {
            StringBuilder JsonString = new StringBuilder();

            //Exception Handling        

            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                JsonString.Append("[ ");
                JsonString.Append("{ ");
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    JsonString.Append("{ ");
                    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (j < dt.Columns.Count - 1)
                        {
                            JsonString.Append("\"" + dt.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString() + "\":" + "\"" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "\",");
                        }
                        else if (j == dt.Columns.Count - 1)
                        {
                            JsonString.Append("\"" + dt.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString() + "\":" + "\"" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "\"");
                        }
                    }

                    /*end Of String*/

                    if (i == dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                    {
                        JsonString.Append("} ");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        JsonString.Append("}, ");
                    }
                }
                JsonString.Append("}]");
                return JsonString.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

     public static string getcountry()
        {
            country c = default(country);
            List<country> cntrylist = new List<country>();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("table1");
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {

                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("getcountry", connection))
                {
                    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    connection.Close();
                    string s = CreateJsonParameters(dt);
                    return s;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: how did you fix this. I'm facing the same issue. Everything comes back, but when i try to access the value, it says undefined. Looking around but if you have found the fix, could you please post it?

Answer (score 0):

At first I recommend that you use an [Ajax Enabled WCF service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924552.aspx) and not build the Json data yourself. If you don't want to use WCF, at least use a JSON library. It is easy to return malformed json data if you do that without a proper library.

Also, why are you using response.d? The d object is returned by an Asp service. If you aren't using one, why to include it?

Finally, check with Firebug or some other means that the returned json is well formed. If in doubt, post it here.

Comment: Trying with library from ajaxpro.com.. There I'm getting the error as "Specified method is not supported" when I used ((IJavaScriptConverter)new AjaxPro.DataTableConverter()).TrySerializeValue(o, type, sb)) method from that library..